# How can I use kubectl --server-dry-run to output the final response body of an apply?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

kubectl supports `--server-dry-run` so that modifications are not persisted but changes from admission controllers etc. are applied. The default output looks something like the following:

```
$ kubectl apply --server-dry-run -f deployment.yaml
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment created (server dry run)
```

However, adding `-v=8` shows me the response body with the actual JSON content that will be persisted to etcd. Is there any way to ask kubectl to print that in a nicer format without some crazy grepping etc.?

Comment: Did you try to run `kubectl apply --server-dry-run -f deployment.yaml -o json`.

Comment: nice that works, will mark as correct if you post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the appropriate Json by using following command:

```
kubectl apply --server-dry-run - f deployment.yaml -o json
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `kubectl diff -f deployment.yaml` to see what changed.